# Converting IP addresses to Hex

Tags: python

How do I make the following conversion using python?

```
"172.1.3.1" >> "\xAC\x01\x03\x01"
```

currently I am able to make the following conversion:

```
"172.1.3.1" >> "AC010301"
```

However I require my results to have the hexadecimal escape characters as shown above.

Comment: `''.join(chr(int(i)) for i in "172.1.3.1".split('.'))`

Comment: ''.join(str("%0.2X"%(int(i))) for i in "172.1.3.1".split('.'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `socket` module, if you are using Python 2.

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.inet_aton("172.1.3.1")
'\xac\x01\x03\x01'
```

This utilizes [`inet_aton`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton):

> Convert an IPv4 address from dotted-quad string format (for example, '123.45.67.89') to 32-bit packed binary format, as a string four characters in length.

---

If you are using Python 3:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address("172.1.3.1").packed
b'\xac\x01\x03\x01'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> socket.inet_aton('172.1.3.1')
'\xac\x01\x03\x01'
>>> struct.pack('>I', IPy.IP('172.1.3.1').int())
'\xac\x01\x03\x01'
```